# Populating dropdownlist and checkboxlist using Ui layer and Data Layer best practice asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, checkboxlist

> I am getting the result i want with the below code.
>   but my question is am i doing it right?
>   please post some modification if my code needs to be modified
>   i am new in c# and trying to learn how to pass data from Ui layer to Data  layer

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddList" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>

        <asp:CheckBoxList ID="cbList" runat="server"></asp:CheckBoxList>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;


namespace test2
{
    public class Data
    {
        string connection = "Data Source=Test\\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog = RegistrationDB;Integrated Security=SSPI";

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();

        public Data()
        {

            conn.ConnectionString = connection;

        }


        public SqlConnection getConnection()
        {

            return conn;

        }

        public DataTable LoadCountry()
        {

            DataTable dtable = new DataTable();

            string select = "SELECT ID,country FROM dbo.Country";

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connection))
            {

                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(select, conn);

                adapter.Fill(dtable);

                return dtable;

            }

        }


        public DataTable LoadChkboxList()
        {

            DataTable position = new DataTable();

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connection))
            {

                string select = "SELECT ID,chkPosition FROM dbo.checkPosition";

                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(select, conn);

                adapter.Fill(position);

                return position;

            }


        }
    }
}




using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;

namespace test2
{
    public partial class UI : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        Data datalayer = new Data();

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!this.IsPostBack)
            {

                ddList.DataSource = datalayer.LoadCountry();
                ddList.DataTextField = "country";
                ddList.DataValueField = "ID";              
                ddList.DataBind();

                cbList.DataSource = datalayer.LoadChkboxList();
                cbList.DataTextField = "chkPosition";
                cbList.DataValueField = "ID";
                cbList.DataBind();

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit modification

```
public DataTable getData(string query)
{
     DataTable dtable = new DataTable();
     using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(YourConnectionString)){
         using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query,con){
              SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
              return adapter.Fill(dt);
         } 
     }
}
```

Note: you can put above function in a class and call where you need. Also can be modified to accept parameters. To avoid SQL Injection, void inline queries, use stored procedures (perferably).

```
DataTable dt Country = getData(YourQuery);
```

Look at: [Parameterized Query and Stored Procedures](http://-parameters-for-sql-server-queries-and-stored-procedures)

Comment: thank you so much for the reply. it is highly appreciated. is it really neccessary or a good practice wring the query as parameter in my method? because if i pass it in the Ui layer i will need to add a query parameter as well. thanks

Comment: If you are performing DB operations with ADO.Net (as you are doing), recommended to have a class to call database operations. Stored procedures preferred over queries. don't forget to accept my reply as Answer , if it helped you :)

Comment: your answers are helping me alot. thanks man. this is my first post in stackoverflow so i bet if i marked anything as an answer my question will be closed? yes i will consider including stored proc to avoid sql injection. but let me look for other comments first before marking urs as an answer. thanks and have a good day and godbless :)

Comment: It'll remain open for answers and comments even though you accept as answer :)

Comment: What if we modify `using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(YourConnectionString))` line as `using (SqlConnection con = getConnection())`

Comment: @RojalinSahoo it will throw an error as i am returning only conn in getConnection() method?

Comment: thanks @Sami for informing. but i will still look for a better explanation :) thanks

Comment: Sure ... SO is full of great of minds ... wait for more to come